# What is git solution for submodules that need patching?

Tags: git, diff, git-submodules, git-diff, patch

I expect this problem is common, but for the life of me I can't seem to find a good solution:

1. Project Foo requires *third-party* project Bar's source (which I have no control over)
2. Project Foo adds Bar as a submodule, because that's the Git solution to this problem
3. It turns out Bar requires a handful of tiny patches that *will never be merged upstream*, as they are quite specific to Foo

#### In my ideal world:

I could **"commit"** patches to Bar **inside Foo**. This would make sense since these patches are specific to Foo and not applicable to other users of Bar.

#### In the real world:

It seems I have to either provide a custom script that the user runs every time in order to patch its copy of Bar (a pain and quite fragile), or I have to host (and consistently keep up to date) a custom copy of every single third-party repository I need (also a pain, seems quite an overkill for tiny patches, and seems weird for changes that are specific to Foo).

What solution am I supposed to use for this problem? I imagine it's quite common, yet I get the feeling Git's "solution" is that patches always be merged upstream, which is quite a non-starter.

Comment: I vote for hosting the third party code.  In any case, you may end up making patches which are specific only to you.  In this case, hosting such code is the logical thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can, **inside `Foo/Bar` submodule**:

- create a `patch` branch,
- apply your `Foo` specific patches to `Bar`,
- add a remote path to a Bar fork that you own,
- push that `patch` branch to that fork `Bar` remote.

Don't forget to go back in `Foo`, add and commit the new `Bar` SHA1 ([gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309), [special entry in `Foo` index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)) and push `Foo` as well.

Now, each time you will update (git fetch) `Bar` from its original remote (over which you have no control), rebase your `patch` branch over `origin/master` of `Bar`. (Then, as usual, push `Bar` to your `Bar` fork, go back in `Foo`, add, commit and push)